# Make cruisecontrol automatically pick new git branch

Tags: git, continuous-integration, cruisecontrol.net

Does some plugin exist for cruisecontrol that makes it automatically pick up new git branches and build them?
This is what I would like to do:
http://entagen.github.com/jenkins-build-per-branch/

Answer (score 4):

There's no plugin that I am aware of, but we hand-rolled a process ourselves. We use mercurial instead of git, but we use this basic process to do this:

1. We created a custom executable that fires when the ChangeGroup event fires.  It looks like in git's case there is the post-receive hook you could use.
2. This executable asks mercurial for the set of changes that were just pushed and then parses through them to see what repositories and branches have been affected.
3. For each new branch, it finds the template we have set up for that repository, formats the template with the new branch information and adds it to the file "ccnethg.config".  It then touches the main config file (ccnet.config) so cruise control will reload the projects.
4. The main config file (ccnet.config) is set up to look at this file using this handy xml trick:

   This piece goes at the start of ccnet.config:

> <!DOCTYPE cruisecontrol[
>
> ```
>    <!ENTITY hgproject SYSTEM "file:ccnethg.config">
> ```
>
> ]>

Then add this piece down in the main config where you define your projects

> &hgproject;

In case that last point didn't come through very well here is a document that describes it.  See the section Splitting the ccnet.config file: http://build.sharpdevelop.net/ccnet/doc/CCNET/Multiple%20Projects.html

We have it split into a separate file because it's easier to deal with programmatically when adding/removing builds to the file if all there is in the file are the branch builds.

I can provide more details if you would like them.